# dnf can't find package installed by automake

Tags: automake, pkg-config, dnf

I have built and installed several packages via automake (autogen,configure,make, make install).

All succeed, and run fine. But `dnf` doesn't see that any of these packages are installed. The `make install` creates and copies all of the `.pc` files correctly to `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, and `pkg-config --exists <my app>` returns `0`, but `dnf list installed <my app>` says `no matching packages to list`.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Yum (and dnf) keeps a list of installed rpm packages, NOT installed execuables or tarballs.

pkg-config doesnt care if the .pc files cames from an installed rpm package or from compiling a tarball - as long as the .pc files are in correct search path.

So, for yum or dnf to know it was a rpm installed, you must create an rpm. Some source tarballs contain a .spec file in them to help rpms. In te case you may be able to build an rpm by running

```
rpmbuild -tb thetarballpackage.tar.gz
```

(or similar) However, you also then run the risk of creatings (and then installing a rpm that may cause conflicts when attempting to install or update other rpms.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. My issue is that I need the latest version of _**gstreamer**_ and its plugins. But, in a catch 22 situation, one of the plugins requires _**xmms**_, and _**xmms**_ requires _**gstreamer**_. Oh, yeah, to make things even more complicated, I am cross-compiling for an rpi :-).  But making  rpms of all of them sounds like a nice project :-(. Thx for the answer.